# ActionMailer sends both formats in a single email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-email, actionmailer

It's pretty strange behavior. I've defined two templates for an action in `EmployeeMailer`.

```
employee_mailer/
    salary_slips.html.erb
    salary_slips.text.erb
```

And the following is the code that I'm using:

```
def salary_slips(salary_record)
  mail.attachments['#{@record.employee.name}'] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: @record.create_pdf_file.render }
  mail to: @record.employee.official_email, subject: ['Salary Silp for', @date].join(' ')
end
```

The problem is: At the client side, I receive an email that starts with `.text.erb` part, and also includes `.html.erb` part at the end.

The development logs are as fellows:

```
Rendered employee_mailer/salary_slips.html.erb (4.2ms)
Rendered employee_mailer/salary_slips.text.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered employee_mailer/salary_slips.text.erb (0.5ms)
```

I think it should only render `.html.erb` part. Is there any way that I can take control, and send only `.html.erb` part in a single email.

## Note:

I've already used `format` block to explicitly state the formats in following way:

```
mail to: @record.employee.official_email, subject: ['Salary Slip for', @date].join(' ') do |format|
  format.html { render 'salary_slips' }
  format.text { render 'salary_slips' }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange to post the answer, but it resolved when I changed `mail.attachments` to just `attachments`. Here's the line that I changed:

```
attachments['#{@record.employee.name}'] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: @record.create_pdf_file.render }
```

Now, it is sending only HTML part, and not the plain text part to one single recipient.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behaviour of ActionMailer - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails

If you only want the HTML part to be rendered you'll have to remove the .text.erb template.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
     default from: 'notifications@example.com'

     def welcome_email(user)
        @user = user
        @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
        mail(to: @user.email,
        subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site') do |format|
        format.html { render 'another_template' }
        format.text { render text: 'Render text' }
   end
 end
```

end

you can select respond format. For more details 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: I just edited my question. I've tried what you said, but didn't help either.

Comment: template = true ? "welcome_photographer" : "welcome"

mail(:to => "email", 
     :subject => "Welcome to ...", 
     :template_name => template)
try this

Comment: in this case you can select template what you want to render